# One-way data flow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactive-programming

I understand the benefits of one-way data flow and declarative (over imperative) coding in a reactive front-end js framework like react, inferno, or preact.  I'm currently working in a situation where jQuery is the only tool I have available, but I'd like to do what can be done with this inherently-imperative library to approach my coding in a more reactive way.

**Is there a way to achieve one-way data flow and declarative style in a jQuery-driven page?**

I'm ok knowing that any bit of code someone writes *could* step in and wreck things that my code assumes will be governed by the reactive bits of code I write; I can probably wrap my code in a plugin and have that be the approach used in that realm and declare that DOM managed by the plugin should be able to expect that it's the only thing touching what it manages - kind of silo it off.

I'm ok not having things like SPA routing and redux and all the other goodies.  I *just* want the DOM management to be more sane and predictable and easier to reason about.

Comment: An interesting question, but too broad, in my opinion, for this platform.

Comment: When you think about it, if you store your data in the DOM, you already have one way data flow.  Actually, maybe even two way, :P

Comment: @PatrickHund I think there's probably a good question hiding here.  Any suggestions on how to narrow it to fit better?

Comment: On a side note, I'm not saying it's a good thing to do; I'd much rather just use react.  But the unsavory nature of actually writing such code doesn't, I think, make the question itself a bad question.

Comment: Well, the default recommendation, as you probably know, is to just start trying to do it, and when you run into problems, post the code and ask for specific help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it more, I think the answer is, no *(well, see update below, and also 2nd update)*.

jQuery is a great tool for imperative DOM manipulation.  If I want a reactive library or framework, I should use one - not hope that something fundamentally different can be made to behave in a way contrary to itself.

Perhaps the best one can do is to have a single point in the code that manages a given DOM element and have all the imperative code that needs to get that element to do something call that single control point, rather than wild-west-everyone-have-at-it-free-for-all code where any line in the script could potentially affect any part of the DOM.

---

Update:

After using the jQuery DataTables plugin for a while I'm realizing there is a way to achieve some level of what I'm aiming for in the question.  Granted, it's still not living the dream.  But what I was aiming for was seeing if there was anything that could be done to bring some of the benefits of the underlying principles of React to the jQuery code on a current project.

Here's some of what I've been trying that has yielded a measure of benefit:

- I've put HTML bits in a hidden div at the bottom of the page (by convention) and used data-* attributes to tag them.
- On page load I use jQuery to `.remove()` them and store them in an object named something like `templates` under appropriate keys.
- When I need to represent state in the UI *either initially or when events introduce state change*, I pass the data into a function which `.clone()`s the template, imperatively populates/decorates it with the passed data, and sets the prepared clone as the `.html()` of an appropriate parent in the document (replacing the previous contents if there were any)

Yes, any developer can come along and write imperative code to mutate the DOM outside this pattern.  And yes, it's a long way from everything React achieves.  But it has at least allowed me to have the beginnings of the UI being a reflection of state rather than relying on it being something I rely on to store any amount of state.  YMMV, but for those still maintaining jQuery code, it may make life a little easier.

---

2nd Update:

Our team recently dropped support for IE, so with all our supported browsers now able to handle ES6, I've started doing the same thing mentioned as above in the "Update" section, but instead of cloning bits of DOM and decorating them with jQuery, I just use

```
$.html(`My interpolated HTML string with ${values} here.`)
```

which greatly simplifies it and achieves some of the declarative approach I want.